# Call Spring boot clases in Java application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

I created a spring boot application that this use spring data postgresql to access to a database. When I test this application works fine. However, I want to use this application in other project that doesn't use spring.
I have a big project that contains two o four java aplications, I use maven to integrate all this project (through modules). I added the dependency in the java aplication in this way:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDPUM.png)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>databases</groupId>
        <artifactId>databases</artifactId>
        <version>${version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I try to use the class created into the project Spring boot, I have the problem that this uses @Autowired and when I execute the project java, a null pointer error appears because the internal class, that is injected is null.

This is the class created in the java project (don't use spring boot)

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {


    private TagServiceBean tagService = new TagServiceBean ();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        Collection<Tag> tags = tagService.findAll();
        for (Tag tag : tags){
           selectedTags.getItems().add(tag.getF_tagname());
        }       
    }
}
```

In the line "Collection tags = TagService.findAll(); I have the following error:

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at org.tenergia.historicosFX.Main.start(Main.java:15)
at        com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at     org.tenergiaEditor.databases.service.spring.TagServiceBean.findAll(TagServiceBean.java:21)
at       org.tenergia.historicosFX.controller.MainController.initialize(MainController.ja    va:134)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
... 17 more
```

Comment: Can you post more code?  Is your boot application called "databases"?  In order for `@Autowired` to work, you need to perform component scanning of the package so the beans can get created.  Are you doing that?

Comment: I'm guessing that the issue lies in your Spring Boot configuration.  https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/

Comment: Yes "databases" is my springboot application, and I do component scaning in the main class of databases. The problem is that in the Java application, where I want to use the services created in spring boot application, I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming in `TagServiceBean` you are using `@Autowired` to inject other dependencies into fields. These fields are not automatically filled with values since you do not use Spring in your "Java Project".

You can either fill all those fields by hand (which would be quite cumbersome) or you use Spring in your "Java Project" to let Spring to the dirty work.

Comment: I understand but, I can't change the java project to a Spring project. I try to put "autowired" in tagServiceBean, but I have the same null pointer error. I don't know if it is possible call from java project to a spring project. I suppose that yes, but I don't know how.